# How much the principal get increased?

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

Assuming that the rate of interest is i=a, an investment of 1 will increase to 4 after n years. Find the accumulated value of 1 after n years, when the rate of interest is i'=3a. (hint: the answer is 64)

(I already know that (1+a)^n=4, (1+3a)^n=x and I don't know what to do after that because I am a beginner. The exercise doesn't clarify that it is a compound interest, but we have said earlier that when it is not clarified it's compound.)

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! What have you done? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I greatly suspect that compound  continuously is assumed here (and in actuarial sciences, that wouldn't surprise me). Then it works! If not, I would have a counter example to your given numbers.

Comment: To avoid future downvotes, and to help the community help you, try to include that kind of thing in your question :)  (I didn't downvote btw)

Comment: @AustinWeaver. He is new here, but you are certainly right!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, hope it's better now!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. If we assume compound continuously ($A=Pe^{rt}$), then with rate $a$ and principal $1$, we arrive at $1e^{4a}=4$ from the given. When we change the rate into $3a$, then the formula becomes $1e^{12a}$ (literally "replace" $a$ by $3a$), which is $1(e^{{4a}})^3$. From here the $64$ logically follows by rules of exponents.

Comment: If I understood right, when we have compound interest, a=e^δt transforms to a=e^rt, so that the force of interest δ equals to r?

Comment: Not just compound interest, compounded continuously. That $r$ in the formula is the rate, which you called $a$, This got to be it, because if it is not compounded continuously, there are plenty of counter examples with the numbers you have given